# Calling generic static method on all types implementing a specific interface

Tags: c#, reflection

Here is my extension method:

```
public static class ComponentExtensions
{
    public static bool TryFindComponent<T>(this Component parentComponent, out T foundComponent)
    {
        foundComponent = parentComponent.GetComponent<T>();
        return foundComponent != null;
    }
}
```

I have an interface `IMyInterface`.

At run-time, I want to iterate through all the types that implement `IMyInterface`, and then invoke `TryFindComponent<T>` until it returns `true`.

```
IEnumerable<Type> grabbableTypes =
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                         .GetAssemblies()
                         .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                         .Where(type => typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type));

foreach (var type in grabbableTypes)
{
    // Call TryFindComponent<T>: 
    // if true, do something to the object assigned to the "out" variable, and then return immediately; 
    // otherwise, continue  
}
```

My question is: How can I pass all the types that implement `IMyInterface` to `TryFindComponent<T>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Answer (score 0):

Besides just the *types* that implement `IMyInterface`, you'll need *instances of* those types to be able to call a method on them.

If the implementations have parameterless constructors you could use

```
var instance = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(myIMyInterfaceType);
```

to create an instance of each matching type.

Then you could add another parameter to `TryFindComponent()` that takes a (collection of) `IMyInterface` instance(s).